# Rails: possible to reference multiple rows belonging to model 1 in a single row in model 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, has-many

I'm new to programming in rails and had a question about referencing multiple rows (instances) from model A in one row in model B?

For example, if I have a model named Paragraph and I had a second model named DocumentOutline, is it possible for a given instance of DocumentOutline to reference multiple instances of Paragraph? The reason is I would like for a user to be able to select which paragraphs are applicable to a given document.

I have done some reading on this topic and I continue running into has_many, belongs_to and has_many :through explanations.

So far, I'm thinking of associating the models as follows:

DocumentOutline has_many :paragraphs
and
Paragraph belongs_to :document_outline

Using this approach a given paragraph could reference a foreign key to indicate which DocumentOutline instance uses given paragraphs.

My issue with that is that I was planning on creating a master database of 'Paragraphs' and did not want that associated directly with any other particular model. Reason being, if I delete a given DocumentOutline, I would not want it to affect the instance(s) of the Paragraph model referencing it.

So, back to my question - is it possible and even advisable to reference multiple rows (instances) of the Paragraph model in the DocumentOutline model? If not, is there another approach aside from what I have described above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"if I delete a given DocumentOutline, **I would not want it to affect** the instance(s) of the Paragraph model referencing it."* What does that mean exactly? Affect it how? The Paragraph will either be orphaned or deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a **master database** of Paragraphs"*?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer in my post: (1) re do not want it affected instances of paragraph model referencing it - I'd rather not have empty columns in the paragrpahs database of it is avoidable (I understand it may not be). (2) re master database - i will also have a second model for derivative paragraphs that are based on the Paragraph model. The term 'master database' was simply descriptive and not meant as a technical use of the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leave paragraph records completely untouched, use `has_many :through` to create a "has and belongs to many" relationship.

Fisrt, create a join model:

```
rails g model ParagraphReference paragraph_id:integer document_outline_id:integer --no-timestamps
```

Run migrations, then set up the associations as follows:

```
class DocumentOutline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraph_references, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :paragraph_references
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraph_references
  has_many :document_outlines, through: :paragraph_references
end

class ParagraphReference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :paragraph
  belongs_to :document_outline
end
```

Benefits of using this association:

- Destroying a document outline will destroy associated paragraph references *without touching the paragraphs*.
- No blank ID columns in paragraphs table (although it doesn't matter).
- Paragraph can be referenced from more than one document outline.
- No modifications to paragraph or document outline schemas needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a given `Paragraph` can be used by at most 1 `DocumentOutline`, keep/use the relationships as you described; your

> if I delete a given DocumentOutline, I would not want it to affect the instance(s) of the Paragraph model referencing it

requirement suggests `dependent: nullify` (cf http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in `DocumentOutline` to me:

```
# app/models/document_outline.rb
class DocumentOutline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraphs, dependent: :nullify
end

# app/models/paragraph.rb
class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document_outline
end
```

Comment: Hi this is very useful and on point with what I was asking. A follow up question: how could I associate more than one DocumentOutline with a given Paragraph instance?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) relationship between them -- take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association